# drupal show/hide certain fields based on author

Tags: drupal

I would like to show / hide certain fields in my Drupal view based on whether the current user is the author of the node being viewed.

I installed the [Views Custom Field module](http://drupal.org/project/views_customfield) which seems to allow this, but I have no  knowledge of PHP, so wondered if anyone could help me with the PHP code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this (*check that $data has uid, maybe different name*):

```
global $user;
if ($user->uid == $data->uid) {
  print 'something';
}
```

Comment: thanks that is very helpful. Another  questoin if you don't mind.

Comment: How do I find out the name of the field I want to print ?

Comment: print_r($data); and you will see in view result some internal of $data

Comment: Hi thanks for yuor help, im getting there. I have the following code,

Comment: <?php
global $user;
$data->to_do;
if ($user->nid == $data->nid)
{
print '[buttons]';
}
?>

The above displays nothing, but if I just add
<?php
print '[buttons]';
?>
Then it works, so I assume its perhaps not using UID ? 

When I run print_r($data);  I get the following output:

stdClass Object ( [nid] => 72 [node_title] => another test task [to_do_deadline] => [to_do_priority] => 1 [to_do_start_date] => [to_do_item_status] => 2 [to_do_nid] => 72 ) 

Thanks for the help I really appreciate it by the way

Comment: Ive just added another field to drupal called user:ID, which then allows the UID token, but the button still does not display.

Comment: thanks for your help, I managed to figure out based on your information.